# Crop visible part of image

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a div with `overflow:hidden` which contains image (`.draggable())` that is usually larger then the div and I need to get only visible part of the image and send it to server side script and save as new file. So my question is, how to get only that visible part?

Thanks!

Comment: it should be doing already that with the overflow hidden, it does not work?

Comment: Yes it does, but i need to retrieve that visible part and send it to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is by getting the x,y position of the draggable. You can get that data by using .top() and .left() on your div. Then you should send the whole image to your server with the **top, left, width, height** data and crop it on your server-side.

Please note that I think that it would be possible to crop it to the Client side by using a **Canvas** HTML5 element and some tricky javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, depending on the method that your are moving your image in the div, save the parameters in inputs using javascript and pass them using POST method when submitting.

For example you pass the TOP and LEFT of image and you already know the WIDTH and HEIGHT of div, so if the left is -375px, you know that you should crop the image from 375px to (375px + div's WIDTH) and same goes for top.

Better option is to use this nice jQuery plugin:

http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the absolute top and left values of the image and compare it with same top and left of the div, take the differences along with the div width and send all this data to server side where you can crop the image via some other programs /library.